# Fastest pcolor-like method with log scale support

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 2d

I've been experimenting with different pcolor-like methods to find the fastest one that would support also log scaling (of the y axis) and some kind of image smoothing (shading or interpolation). I'm asking here to make sure I'm not missing something.

## The goal

The goal is to plot a 2D array `s` representing a scalogram, a `t` array representing time samples and `f` representing logarithmically sampled frequencies. The shapes aren't exactly pcolor-style material, because they represent points, not bounds: `s.shape == (f.size, t.size)`. Ideally I would want a method that takes point coordinates, not bounds.

The result should be fast enough for interactive plotting with sizes `map(log10, s.shape)` around (3-4, 2-3).

## My research so far

- `matplotlib.image.NonUniformImage`

  - provides exactly the interface I would want, it expects point coordinates
  - is very fast
  - supports bilinear interpolation
  - does not support log scales. The axis ticks are rescaled after a call to `yscale('log')`, but the image isn't.
  - uses `matplotlib.image.pcolor` internally, which is undocumented

    - the [code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/src/_image.h) seems to show that it does not support larger arrays
- `matplotlib.image.PcolorImage` is very similar to the above

  - has a pcolor-style interface
  - has the same deficiencies regarding log scaling.
  - uses `matplotlib.image.pcolor2` internally, which is undocumented

    - judging by the [code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/src/_image.h) it does not support interpolation
- `matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolorfast`:

  - for 1D point coordinates uses `PcolorImage`
  - for 2D point coordinates (created e.g. by meshgrid) uses `QuadMesh` which supports log scaling.

    - does not support gouraud shading
- `matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh` seems to be the winner so far

  - supports gouraud shading, but that is quite slow
  - also uses `QuadMesh`, I could not find any significant speedups in pcolorfast in the quadmesh case (when not using gouraud shading).

## Alternative approaches

An alternative is to use `contourf`, but with many levels it will slow down too.

Another possibility is to use `NonUniformImage` or even `imshow`, but scale the coordinates and handle axis ticks manually.

Comment: This should probably be a feature request on github.

Comment: @tcaswell I'm not sure what I'd request, because `pcolormesh` already works, it's just that it's slow. I could request that `pcolorfast` be polished and finished off, but the docs pretty much label it as WIP, so they know about it.

Comment: I think a pcolor with fast rendering and interpolating capability is more useful.

Comment: `pcolormesh` can  do something like interpolation with `shading='gouraud'`